# Laravel Ajax Call through entire page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to run an Ajax post call through my entire application, it shall update the Navigation. On some pages it works but on others it does not, how can I fix this and make it global so to say.

I am using Laravel as a php Framework.

```
# Middleware group if user is logged in
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
     # Notifications
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'notification', 'as' => 'notification.'], function () {
        Route::post('number', ['as' => 'number', 'uses' => 'NotificationController@number']);
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'relation', 'as' => 'relation.'], function () {
        Route::get('show/{id}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'RelationController@show']);
    });
});
```

in my layouts/app.blade.php I include the js file like this

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/liveUpdater.js') }}"></script>
@yield('javascript')
```

the liveUpdater ajax function

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'number',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#number-of-notifications').text(data.unread);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('error number ' + data.data);
    }
});
```

The Url http://localhost/myApp/public/notification/all returns a success message.

But an url for example like this http://localhost/myApp/public/relation/show/1 Returns an error message:

> ```
> number
> /myApp/public/relation/show
> 405
> Method Not Allowed
> ```

Comment: You get this error either when you making a POST request to a route defined to accept GET  request  or a GET request to one defined to accept POST

Answer (score 1):

You are prefixing the route with `notification` so your ajax request should point to `notification/number`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'notification/number',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#number-of-notifications').text(data.unread);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('error number ' + data.data);
    }
});
```

Also I think aliasing (in the group) wouldn't help, so I think (for simplicity) you could have:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
     # Notifications
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'notification'], function () {
        Route::post('number', 'NotificationController@number']);
    });
});
```

[Routing groups docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups)

Comment: This does not work in a uri like this: `http://localhost/app/public/relation/show/1` or this `http://localhost/app/public/notification/all` it Returns a 404, if I open up `http://localhost/app/public/notification/all` it Points to `/app/public/notification/notification/number` for example

Comment: Ahh...they are not defined as I can clearly see in the routes you have provided...

Comment: they are but the Ajax URL post thems in the wrong direction, I add the relation/Show route in the question above as an example

Answer (score 0):

You've to define route path and corresponding controller methods for every url paths like for relation/show and notification/all :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
     # Notifications
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'notification'], function () {
        Route::post('show/{show}', 'NotificationController@show']);
        Route::post('number', 'NotificationController@number']);
        Route::post('all ', 'NotificationController@all']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mistake in your request method in ajax. it should be   type: "GET", OR in your web.php like Route::post('show/{id}' instead of Route::get('show/{id}'

your request method is not matching that why its throwing 405